# Stop button is not working

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

This is a code for play and stop mediaplayer
It made music successfully and played that.But stop button didn't work
Why it's not working?
Please lead me to the correct code
Thanks

```
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Titraj/"+name+".mp3"));


    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

         @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pa);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
               if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.stop();
                    }
             }  
        }
        });

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play); 

        }
    });
```

Comment: Try removing the null check inside the mp.isPlaying() if statement

Comment: Why do an mp != null check after you've already used mp in the line before it?

Comment: I removed it.But it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one....

```
stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
       if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
   }
    }
 });
```

Also must check you haven't set **android:focusable = false** for your button in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your on stop method

```
mp.stop();
mp.release();
mp= null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Titraj/"+name+".mp3"));


    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

         @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.pause();
                        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(mp!=null){
                        mp.start();
                        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pa);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
               if(mp.isPlaying()){

                        mp.stop();



             }  
        }
        });

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play); 

        }
    });


Check this code i hop it working....
```

Comment: Maybe add some commentary